# Baseball metaphor, equivalent to 'lay your body on the line'

Tags: american-english, metaphors, sports

The English expression 'you need to be prepared to lay your body on the line' is a football metaphor, referring to the potentially painful act of lying down on the goal line to prevent a goal being scored against you.

I have heard there is an American expression which means almost the same thing involving baseball. Can anyone please remind me?

Comment: How about "If you're a catcher, prepare to be cleated if you insist on blocking the runner's access to home plate"?  Seriously, the only thing I can think of is the notion of hitting a sacrifice fly so that a runner can advance to home plate.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you are thinking of "[taking one for the team](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_one_for_the_team)"?

That's not baseball specific though, except that it can mean allowing yourself to be hit by the ball while you are at bat, so that you are automatically advanced to first base (and therefore advance the runners, potentially scoring).

If you're thinking specifically about blocking a score, "[covering your bases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_a_base)" is from baseball and means to literally cover the base to attempt to prevent a runner from scoring (or advancing). It doesn't have a particularly painful connotation though, whereas taking one for the team certainly does.

Answer (score 2):

Mention of 'plate' has reminded me. Don't you talk about 'stepping up to the plate'? 'Taking one for the team' sounds a good one too.  That means more or less the same thing as being 'prepared to lay your body on the line'. Sporting metaphors are very effective. Cricket has a vast number.

Comment: To which the average American who does not appreciate the pageantry can sadly only respond with cricket sounds. You know - chirp, chirp :)

Comment: @AffableGeek Pageantry? You obviously know nothing about 'The ashes series', Cricket matches between England and Australia. Life and death struggles!

Comment: I like "stepping up to the plate" while it doesn't have the obvious self-sacrifice of "lay your body on the line" it does bring forward the idea of shouldering your responsibilities.

Comment: 'Stepping up to the plate' is like squaring your shoulders as you prepare to do your job when the going gets tough. It's that breathless moment as you swallow your anxiety, and get ready for what is to come. Is that what you are going for?

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to someone "hitting a sac fly" or "bunting," although admittedly neither of those are particularly commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

The expression is *guarding the plate*, in which the catcher uses his body to attempt to slow the runner down as he [the catcher] attempts to tag him out with the ball arriving at nearly the same moment.

It is well expected that [guarding the plate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_the_plate) may involve a collision with the runner, as in the iconic play at home in the movie "A League of Their Own", which allows the runner to score if the catcher is unable to haold onto the ball.

The term is sometimes phrased as *blocking the plate*, with the same intent and meaning. I no of no standard distinction between the two phrasings.

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of *lay out*: to dive in order to catch a ball.  It's used as an intransitive verb, as in, *Smith laid out to rob Jones of a double.*

This usage doesn't appear in any of the dictionaries I found, but a Google search for `"lay out" fly ball baseball` gives a number of examples, and I recall hearing radio announcers use it pretty frequently.